# Two-dimensional mean/95% LOA plot

Tags: data-visualization, scatterplot

I have a data set consisting of automated versus manual segmentation of images. For a given measurement point, comparison between the automated and manual method are reported via Jaccard coefficient and mean area difference.

I had an idea to present both results in the same plot as a scatter of Jaccard coefficient versus mean area difference, with mean and 95% LOA for both Jaccard and mean area difference. This creates a 95% LOA "box" within which results are displayed.

It actually makes interpreting the graph quite intuitive, which is nice. However, I've never seen this and I'm unsure if it's appropriate. For one thing, one loses the "error vs. mean" interpretation from a standard Bland-Altman plot.

Something like this (let A be the mean difference and B be the Jaccard coefficient):

[image]

Is this the canonical way to present results when two evaluation criteria are under consideration? Or should I present some different plot for the Jaccard coefficients, with a standard Bland-Altman for the mean area difference?

Comment: Perhaps 2D whiskers/error bars like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21296939/210945

Comment: As for me, your plot is clear and intuitive for this data.

Comment: Your plot assumes (implicitly) that the two metrics are independent, but they might not be. You could use a density estimator, like [this](http://www.sthda.com/sthda/RDoc/figure/ggplot2/ggplot2-scatter-plot-geom-density-2d-data-visualization-1.png). You could also plot histograms along each axis, like [this](http://www.originlab.com/doc/Origin-Help/Marginal-Histograms-Graph). On the other hand, by the looks of it, the data are pretty close to independent for this plot, so maybe it doesn't matter in this case, and it's possible you don't have enough data for a good density estimate anyway.

Comment: @naug101 Thanks for the alternative suggestions. I get the implicit assumption, but I'm not sure I see how it could lead to a misleading interpretation...?